# Better String formatting in Scala

Tags: string, scala, formatting, string-formatting

With too many arguments, `String.format` easily gets too confusing. Is there a more powerful way to format a String. Like so:

```
"This is #{number} string".format("number" -> 1)
```

Or is this not possible because of type issues (`format` would need to take a Map[String, Any], I assume; don’t know if this would make things worse).

Or is the better way doing it like this:

```
val number = 1
<plain>This is { number } string</plain> text
```

even though it pollutes the name space?

**Edit:**

While a simple pimping might do in many cases, I’m also looking for something going in the same direction as Python’s `format()` (See: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: FWIW, I disagree that one ever needs to be in a situation where `String.format` has too many arguments.  Use two or more strings; concat with `+`.  But of course it would be nice if someone took the time to clone the python format for those people who prefer that style to the C style.

Comment: Sure, there are not so many applications but sometimes you just want to externalise a template string and then the advantage is evident in my opinion. Or for internationalisation stuff (though I don’t know if e.g. even the Python format is powerful enough for that).

Comment: But shouldn’t there be such a thing for Java already?

Comment: @Always-Asking (via [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6219208)): Those tags probably weren't in existence when this question was posted; the addition does make sense though.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In Scala 2.10 you can use [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html).

```
val height = 1.9d
val name = "James"
println(f"$name%s is $height%2.2f meters tall")  // James is 1.90 meters tall
```

Answer (score 46):

Well, if your only problem is making the order of the parameters more flexible, this can be easily done:

```
scala> "%d %d" format (1, 2)
res0: String = 1 2

scala> "%2$d %1$d" format (1, 2)
res1: String = 2 1
```

And there's also regex replacement with the help of a map:

```
scala> val map = Map("number" -> 1)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map((number,1))

scala> val getGroup = (_: scala.util.matching.Regex.Match) group 1
getGroup: (util.matching.Regex.Match) => String = <function1>

scala> val pf = getGroup andThen map.lift andThen (_ map (_.toString))
pf: (util.matching.Regex.Match) => Option[java.lang.String] = <function1>

scala> val pat = "#\\{([^}]*)\\}".r
pat: scala.util.matching.Regex = #\{([^}]*)\}

scala> pat replaceSomeIn ("This is #{number} string", pf)
res43: String = This is 1 string
```

Answer (score 18):

You can easily implement a richer formatting yourself (with the "enhance my library" approach):

```
scala> implicit def RichFormatter(string: String) = new {
     |   def richFormat(replacement: Map[String, Any]) =
     |     (string /: replacement) {(res, entry) => res.replaceAll("#\\{%s\\}".format(entry._1), entry._2.toString)}
     | }
RichFormatter: (string: String)java.lang.Object{def richFormat(replacement: Map[String,Any]): String}

scala> "This is #{number} string" richFormat Map("number" -> 1)
res43: String = This is 1 string
```

Or on more recent Scala versions since the original answer:

```scala
implicit class RichFormatter(string: String) {
  def richFormat(replacement: Map[String, Any]): String =
    replacement.foldLeft(string) { (res, entry) =>
      res.replaceAll("#\\{%s\\}".format(entry._1), entry._2.toString)
    }
}
```

Comment: True, I might even use `%` for that (as in some other languages). But still, it could be a bit more powerful… (Like python’s format maybe.)

Answer (score 18):

This the answer I came here looking for:

```
"This is %s string".format(1)
```

Answer (score 17):

Maybe the Scala-Enhanced-Strings-Plugin can help you. Look here:

[Scala-Enhanced-Strings-Plugin Documentation](http://jrudolph.github.com/scala-enhanced-strings/Overview.scala.html)

Comment: Looks pretty interesting. (Both the docu and the plugin.) But still a bit crazy (also both) because the syntax does not use any delimiters sometimes…

Comment: I'm using it in production and it's great!  Delimiters are only required when the expression to be interpolated has much syntax beyond just a variable name.

Comment: For 2.10+ users, definitely check out the built in string interpolation at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html.  Thanks to Andrej for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using 2.10 then go with built-in interpolation. Otherwise, if you don't care about extreme performance and are not afraid of functional one-liners, you can use a fold + several regexp scans:

```
val template = "Hello #{name}!"
val replacements = Map( "name" -> "Aldo" )
replacements.foldLeft(template)((s:String, x:(String,String)) => ( "#\\{" + x._1 + "\\}" ).r.replaceAllIn( s, x._2 ))
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider the use of a template engine for really complex and long strings. On top of my head I have [Scalate](https://github.com/scalate/scalate) which implements amongst others the [Mustache](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/mustache.html#features) template engine.

Might be overkill and performance loss for simple strings, but you seem to be in that area where they start becoming real templates.