# Scala support for string templates?

Tags: scala, templates, template-engine

Is there default (in SDK) Scala support for string templating? Example: "$firstName $lastName"(named not numbered parameters) or even constructs like for/if. If there is no such default engine, what is the best scala library to accomplish this?

Comment: update: named parameters are preferred.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better String formatting in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051308/better-string-formatting-in-scala)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Complementing [Kim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46450/kim-stebel) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236931/scala-string-template/6236975#6236975), note that Java's `Formatter` accepts positional parameters. For example:

```
"%2$s %1$s".format(firstName, lastName)
```

Also, there's the [Enhanced Strings](http://jrudolph.github.com/scala-enhanced-strings/Overview.scala.html) plugin, which allows one to embed arbitrary expressions on Strings. For example:

```
@EnhanceStrings // enhance strings in this scope
trait Example1 {
  val x = 5
  val str = "Inner string arithmetics: #{{ x * x + 12 }}"
}
```

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051308/better-string-formatting-in-scala) for more answers, as this is really a close duplicate.

Comment: +1 for the Enhanced Strings compiler plugin - no, it's not SDK, but it does a pretty good job

Answer (score 10):

If you want a templating engine, I suggest you have a look at [scalate](http://scalate.fusesource.org/). If you just need string interpolation, `"%s %s".format(firstName, lastName)` is your friend.

Answer (score 6):

In Scala 2.10 and up, you can use [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)

```
val name = "James"
println(s"Hello, $name")  // Hello, James

val height = 1.9d
println(f"$name%s is $height%2.2f meters tall")  // James is 1.90 meters tall
```

Comment: If I need to read the template "$name%s is $height%2.2f meters tall" from a file? Or just have it in a var/val?

Answer (score 1):

This compiler plug-in has provided string interpolation for a while:

http://jrudolph.github.com/scala-enhanced-strings/Overview.scala.html

More recently, the feature seems to be making it into the scala trunk: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/test/files/run/stringInterpolation.scala -- which generates some interesting possiblities: https://gist.github.com/a69d8ffbfe9f42e65fbf (not sure if these were possible with the plug-in; I doubt it).