# Scala string formatting

Tags: scala

```
val height = 1.9d
val name = "James"
println(f"$name%s is $height%2.2f meters tall")  // James is 1.90 meters tall
```

I've seen this example both at [Better String formatting in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051308/better-string-formatting-in-scala)  and in the Scala docs.

What does the 2 after % stand for?  I assume the 2f means two decimal places.

Comment: Read here for more details - http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Answer (score 3):

Scala [string interpolation formats](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) actually use [java's Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) behind the scenes .

The format string has the following format :

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

In your case the format string is using a `float` conversion ( the `f` at the end)

So your format string is asking for a float conversion with a width of `2` and a precision of `2`

In the same way `%4.10f` would request a float conversion with a width of `4`and a precision of `10`.

- Passing `1.9d` to the format String `%4.10f` would result in the string 
  `1,9000000000`
- Passing `1.9d` to the format String `%10.4f`would result in the string 
      `1,9000` (it would be padded to a width of 10 with whitespace)

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 indicates the minimum number of characters that you want printed in the output, and second 2 would indicate the number of digits after the decimal point that you need.

Suppose you instead had "%5.2f", and the 'height' was 1.2,
it would result in `' 1.20'` (with the space in the beginning) [not the quotes; they are here for clarity]

The docs refer to them as Width and Precision respectively (%[width].[precision]).

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html
(this points to the docs for the java Formatter)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html