# Could anyone explain this spark expression for me?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm a new learner of spark. There's one line of code estimating pi but I don't quite understand how it works.

```
scala>val pi_approx = f"pi = ${355f/113}%.5f"
pi_approx: String = pi = 3.14159
```

I don't understand the 'f' '$' and '%' in the expression above. Could anyone explain the usage of them? Thanks!

Comment: its just formating the number . 355f is a float number devided by 113 . .5f denotes to show until five decimal places. $ to match the floating number  and f in the front denote the floating number denoted by $ inside "" string for more info read https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful! ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better String formatting in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051308/better-string-formatting-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

This is the example of String Interpolation that allows users to embed variable references directly in processed string literals. For e.g.

```
scala> val name = "Scala"
name: String = Scala

scala> println(s"Hello, $name")
Hello, Scala
```

In above example the literal `s"Hello, $name"` is a processed string literal.

Scala provides three string interpolation methods out of the box: `s`, `f` and `raw`.
Prepending `f` to any string literal allows the creation of simple formatted strings, similar to `printf` in other languages.

The formats allowed after the `%` character tells that result is formatted as a decimal number while `${}` allows any arbitrary expression to be embedded. For e.g.

```
scala> println(s"1 + 1 = ${1 + 1}")
1 + 1 = 2
```

More detailed information can be found on:

- [Scala String Interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)
- [Java Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#detail)