# How to use String.format() in scala

Tags: scala, date, string.format

I am new to Scala world, I wanted to use String.format() to create a date format string.
I have three integer value year month and day, I wanted to change it in yyyy-mm-dd. String.format() expect an array of Anyref, when I am creating Array[Anyref] by passing integer value to it, it is throwing below error.

Error:(49, 30) the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
    dd(2) = inputCalendar.get(5)

My full example is :

```
val dd = new Array[AnyRef](3);
dd(0) = Integer.valueOf(inputCalendar.get(1))
dd(1) = Integer.valueOf(inputCalendar.get(2) + 1)
dd(2) = inputCalendar.get(5)
println(String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d",dd))
```

Note: I don't want to use any Date API for this.

Comment: What is `inputCalendar`?

Comment: Please check; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051308/better-string-formatting-in-scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare `dd` elements as type `Int` and this should work.

```
val dd = new Array[Int](3)
. . . //unchanged
String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d",dd:_*)
```

Or ...

```
"%04d-%02d-%02d".format(dd:_*)
```

Comment: with solution 1, I am getting below error.

Error:(54, 20) overloaded method value format with alternatives:
  (x$1: java.util.Locale,x$2: String,x$3: Object*)String <and>
  (x$1: String,x$2: Object*)String
 cannot be applied to (String, Int)
    println(String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d",dd:_*))

But second solution is working for me. Thank you so much.